# swing horizontal scroll bar problem

Tags: swing

```
 public TaskGraphComponent(ProjectFrame proFrame,TaskGraphModel model,    painter) {
    this.proFrame = proFrame;
    _painter = painter;

     setModel(model);
     _mouseHandler = new GraphMouseHandler(this);
    _verticalScroll = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
    this.add(_verticalScroll, BorderLayout.EAST); 

    _verticalScroll.addAdjustmentListener(this);
    _verticalScroll.setVisible(true);
    _horizontalScroll = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
    add(_horizontalScroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
   _horizontalScroll.addAdjustmentListener(this);
    _horizontalScroll.setVisible(true);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,15,0));
    this.addMouseMotionListener(_mouseHandler);
    this.addMouseListener(_mouseHandler);
    this.addMouseWheelListener(_mouseHandler);
    this.addKeyListener(_mouseHandler);
    this.addComponentListener(this);
    this.setFocusable(false);
    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(8000);
    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setReshowDelay(3000);

}
```

I'm extending from **JComponent** here vertical scroll bar working fine but horizontal 
scroll is not showing.

Here TaskGraphComponent is jcomponent

Comment: Try this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AquickdemonstrationofJScrollBarbothverticalandhorizontal.htm).

Comment: @Asad Rasheed actually i tired information present in link but same problem

Comment: what are that, It seems you are not using layout?

Comment: can you try these ? **this.add(_verticalScroll, BorderLayout.EAST);**
**add(_horizontalScroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);**

Comment: I updated the code as Answer that is working fine for me.

Comment: please see my code which is posted

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: thank u i got horizontal scroll

Comment: it showing horizontal can help me  how to adjust horizontal scroll

Answer (score 1):

> ..not using any layout..

That is the problem.  **Use layouts.**

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code please run it and let me know. I change the code from the above link:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AquickdemonstrationofJScrollBarbothverticalandhorizontal.htm

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;

public class SwingScrollBarExample extends JComponent implements AdjustmentListener {

  JLabel label;

  public SwingScrollBarExample() {
    label = new JLabel();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JScrollBar _verticalScroll = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
    this.add(_verticalScroll);

    _verticalScroll.addAdjustmentListener(this);
    _verticalScroll.setVisible(true);

    JScrollBar _horizontalScroll = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
    this.add(_horizontalScroll);

    _horizontalScroll.addAdjustmentListener(this);
    _horizontalScroll.setVisible(true);

    this.add(_verticalScroll, BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.add(_horizontalScroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }

   public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
      label.setText("    New Value is " + e.getValue() + "      ");
      repaint();
   }

  public static void main(String s[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scroll Bar Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new SwingScrollBarExample());
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: when i use this code it shows _verticalScroll.setMaximum(canScrollUp + canScrollDown)  nullpointer Expection

Comment: @Ganesh: and what are **canScrollUp + scanScrollDown**, means what values in these variables?